# can anyone give me an idea about how to export an Dundas OLAP grid to excell

Tags: c#, olap-cube

I am new to Dundas, I would like to export the olap grid to excell. I dont know how to do it. can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the ASP version:

```
Dim myResponse As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim strToExport As String

        OlapGrid.Export(strm)

        Dim streamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(strm)
        strm.Position = 0
        strToExport = streamReader.ReadToEnd

        Try
            myResponse.Clear()
            myResponse.Buffer = False
            myResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report2Excel.xls")
            myResponse.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
            myResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
            myResponse.Charset = ""
            myResponse.Write(strToExport)

        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            myResponse.[End]()
        End Try
```

BTw if you know a solution for the KPI images in the grid let me know

Comment: Thx for your reply, also, i got it worked here is the code snipt.

Comment: if (this.IsCallback)
            {return;
            }Byte[] renderedBytes = _presenter.GetRenderedBytes(new MemoryStream(), OlapClient1);
            if (renderedBytes != null && renderedBytes.Length > 0)
            {exporting = true;Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; //"application/pdf"; 
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=temp.xls");
                Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);

                Response.Flush();

Comment: Try this for KPI images http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8390http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8390